# Java erasure conflict in classes that implement Hazelcast MessageListener with different message objects

Tags: java, listener, hazelcast, erasure

Currently using Hazelcast 3.0 and trying to set up different topics with different message objects and I'd like to have classes that can listen to more than one topic, but I don't see how it is possible because the differing onMessage() methods have the same erasure.  Here is my Hazelcast configuration class:

```
import com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast;
import com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance;
import com.hazelcast.core.ITopic;
import com.hazelcast.core.MessageListener;

public class HazelcastHelper {

  //List of Topics
  public static final String TIMER = "TIMER";
  public static final String POINTS = "POINTS";

  public static class TimerMO {}
  public static class PointsMO {}

  private HazelcastInstance hz = null;

  public HazelcastInstance getHazelcastInstance() {
    if (hz == null) {
        hz = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
        ...
    }
    return hz;
  }

  public ITopic<TimerMO> getTimerTopic() {
    return this.getHazelcastInstance().getTopic(TIMER);
  }

  public void publishTimer(TimerMO message) {
    this.getTimerTopic().publish(message);
  }

  public String addTimerListener(MessageListener<TimerMO> messageListener) {
    return this.getTimerTopic().addMessageListener(messageListener);
  }

  public ITopic<PointsMO> getPointsTopic() {
    return this.getHazelcastInstance().getTopic(POINTS);
  }

  public void publishPoints(PointsMO message) {
    this.getPointsTopic().publish(message);
  }

  public String addPointsListener(MessageListener<PointsMO> messageListener) {
    return this.getPointsTopic().addMessageListener(messageListener);
  }
}
```

Then I have, for instance, a super-class that listens for a topic based on one of the message objects:

```
import com.hazelcast.core.Message;
import com.hazelcast.core.MessageListener;

public class TimerListener implements MessageListener<HazelcastHelper.TimerMO> {
  @Override
  public void onMessage(Message<HazelcastHelper.TimerMO> message) {
    ...
  }
}
```

and then a sub-class that listens for a second type of message object:

```
import com.hazelcast.core.Message;
import com.hazelcast.core.MessageListener;

public class PointsListener extends TimerListener implements MessageListener<HazelcastHelper.PointsMO> {
  @Override
  public void onMessage(Message<HazelcastHelper.PointsMO> message) {
    ...
  }
}
```

But, as you might see, this is not allowed because there is an erasure conflict between the super-class and the sub-class which both implement MessageListener, but for different types of MessageObject classes.  Note that I also might like to have one class that listens for both types of messages, that also would work due to erasure conflict.

Am I missing something?  Is this not a normal scenario for using Hazelcast to create topics and listeners?  I would like to keep my implementation clean and not have to introspect the Messages to evaluate what type they are -- it seems to me that Hazelcast did not create a clean design, but maybe I am missing how to set up topics, messages and listeners correctly.  Please help me to understand how to resolve this.

Comment: I think you're implementing MessageListener twice, but with diff args

Comment: @NickBell Thanks for responding, but I realize that -- the issue is that I want to listen for several different messages (i.e., I want to listen for both PointsMO AND TimerMO messages) and I can't see how to do that.

Comment: You can either give them a common type or use Object for the generic ;) Both is more like a workaround though. You hit a Java limitation that cannot be solved, sorry to say :-)

Comment: I don't believe this a Java limitation as much as it is a Hazelcast API design limitation, unless I am missing how to design this to work within their API.